# How can i make an "Gmail" like header buttons? (Pic attached)

Tags: android

Does any one knows how can i skin an android button to look like this:

[a busy cat http://www.11sheep.com/temp/picForSO.jpg](http://www.11sheep.com/temp/picForSO.jpg)

Thanks in advance,
Lior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following layout files will product a button with 5px radius, of course u input your own color and change the solid color to gradient to match ur screenshots, then on the button change the text colour to white or something.. I dont have time for examples now.. good luck though.

and lastly you have to apply them as background to your button like this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLoveThisOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Love me love u too!"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background" <!-- Yes look at me -->
/>
```

button_background_normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/button_background_normal_color"/> <!-- Change this to your own colour -->
    <corners android:radius="5px"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#20ffffff"/>
</shape>
```

button_background_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/button_background_pressed_color"/> <!-- Change this to your own colour -->
    <corners android:radius="5px"/>
</shape>
```

button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_normal" />

    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed" />

    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_normal" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know two ways to make it:

1. a `Button` or `TextView` with an image having that engraving rectangle, for stretch, use 9.patch :)
2. a `Button` or `TextView` with transparent background and a selector drawing the shape border

However, I don't know exactly how they did as shown in your picture.